# sort JS object on multiple items, including Dates

Tags: javascript

trying to work this out but not sure about it really

I have a JSON object which contains multiple items like below

```
DATA_TABLE = [{"rownum": 0, "Surname": "Doe", "Firstname": "John", "Dob": "1 Jan 1980"}...]
```

I want to sort the data by DOB then Surname then firstname, to get the same result like for example the sql statement

```
ORDER BY Dob, Surname, Firstname
```

Comment: try this:DATA_TABLE.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.Dob) - parseFloat(b.Dob) } );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code:

```
DATA_TABLE.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.Dob) - new Date(b.Dob) 
  || ((a.Surname   < b.Surname  ) ? -1 : (a.Surname   > b.Surname  ) ? 1 : 0)
  || ((a.Firstname < b.Firstname) ? -1 : (a.Firstname > b.Firstname) ? 1 : 0) ;
});
```

[JsFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gzmox7t5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Alasql library:

```
 var DATA_TABLE = [{"rownum": 0, "Surname": "Doe", "Firstname": "John", "Dob": "1 Jan 1980"},
          {"rownum": 1, "Surname": "America", "Firstname": "Captain", "Dob": "1 Jan 1940"},];

 var res = alasql('SELECT *, DATE(Dob) AS d FROM ? ORDER BY d, Surname, Firstname',[DATA_TABLE]);
```

Try this example [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/o3vt4dp1/4/).

Due the original Dob column has a string type, I include additional column "d" for proper sorting.